# Add a link for tagged user in a tweet(vuejs)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, hyperlink, tags

Is it possible to add a link to twitter user profile which is tagged in a tweet?
I figured out how do i find tagged users in a text with 'includes', but i am not able to add a link either with '.link' or '.href' attribbute.

```
    axios.post(API_URL, null, { params }).then(res => {

        res.data.tweets.forEach(tweet => {
          const tweetData = {
            id: tweet.id,
            tweet_text: tweet.tweet_text,
            twitter_name: tweet.twitter_name,
            twitter_username: tweet.twitter_username,
            added_at: moment(String(tweet.added_at)).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm'),
          }
          this.tweets.push(tweetData)
          this.tweets.forEach(el => {
            el.tweet_text.split(' ').forEach(word => {
              if (word.includes('@')) {

              }
            })
          })
        })
    })
```

This is component where data is shown

```
        <div class="tweets-container">
          <div
            v-for="tweet in tweets"
            :key="tweet.id"
          >
            <div class="tweet-card">
              <div class="username-time">
                <div class="user-info">
                  <p class="name">
                    {{ tweet.twitter_name }}
                  </p>
                  <p class="user-info-p">
                    @
                  </p>
                  <p class="username">
                    <a
                      :href="'https://twitter.com/' + tweet.twitter_username"
                      class="twitter_link"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      {{ tweet.twitter_username }}
                    </a>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="time">
                  <p>{{ tweet.added_at }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                <p>{{ tweet.tweet_text }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting an messages in developer console ?

Comment: For what? If i log "word" here,  "if (word.includes('@'))", i am getting these words. If i try adding href like this "word.href = 'https://twitter.com'" i got an error "TypeError: Cannot create property 'href' on string".